# dynamic way to find entity repository java spring

Tags: java, spring, repository, entity

I'm trying to implement a dynamic way to reuse and find method for all entities :

```
UserRepository Repository;
Page<User> pages = Repository.findAll(new PageRequest(0,5));
```

how to get repository from object name = user ?

**My method:**

```
public myMethod(Repository rep){ 
    Page<Object> pages = rep.findAll(new PageRequest(0,5));
}
```

**Example:**

```
UserRepository u;
myMethod(u);
```

**Error message:** can't convert UserRepository to Repository

Thanks

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how this would react in your code but have you tried doing: `public myMethod(rep extends Repository)`?